# Roll back last commit in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I updated a project in Android Studio and my friend's commit has overwritten the changes I did.

I did not commit my code and I want to get it back.

Please help me, I am badly in trouble.

Comment: right click on file/Project,  click "Local History" and select "show history". let me know if it works

Comment: Thank u, I undo it by git>repository>unstash changes

Comment: You can give answer by your own, it will help others, if they encounter same problem

Comment: Write it as answer so that anybody who get in this issue can see this post for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on app dir in Android Studio and then

```
Git->Repository->Unstash
```

There is a list of uncommited changes and you can undo the changes from there.

Answer (score 0):

To restore everything back to the way it was prior to the last commit, we need to reset to the commit before HEAD:

`git reset --soft HEAD^     # use --soft if you want to keep your changes
git reset --hard HEAD^     # use --hard if you don't care about keeping the changes you made`

Now `git log` will show that our last commit has been removed.

P.S : You have to run above commands via terminal.